# Inserting an image from local directory in thymeleaf spring framework (with maven)

Tags: html, spring, maven, thymeleaf

I have developed a project using this link: https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/ I used maven to develop above project.

I have two html files under this. abc.html and xyz.html. To insert images in the html page, I have used the url like this:

```
<img src="https://example.com/pic_mountain.jpg" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px">
```

But I want to use an image file located in my server instead. I tried placing the file in the same directory of html file but its not working. I even tried giving full path but of no use. This is an ubuntu OS. Please help me out here. Is there any place where I can configure the base path or basically how to put an image from my local folder.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I want you to look into the Thymeleaf's documentation of [Standard URL Syntax](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html) and specifically the context-relative and server-relative url patterns.

**Context-relative URL:**

> If you want to link resources inside your webapp then you should use
>   context relative urls. These are URLs which are supposed to be
>   relative to the web application root once it is installed on the
>   server. For example, if we deploy a myapp.war file into a Tomcat
>   server, our application will probably be accessible as
>   http://localhost:8080/myapp, and **myapp** will be the context name.

As JB Nizet the following will work for you as I have used thymeleaf personally in a webapp project,

```
<img th:src="@{/images/test.png}"/>
```

and the test.png should be under your project root inside the webapp folder. Something navigated through roughly like,

```
Myapp->webapp->images->test.png
```

*Eg:*

```
<img th:src="@{/resources/images/Picture.png}" />
```

*Output as:*

```
<img src="/resources/image/Picture.png" />
```

When you hit `http://localhost:8080/myapp/resources/images/Picture.png` in you browser then you should be able to access the image for the above syntax to work. And your resources folder will probably under webapp folder of your application.

**Server-relative URL:**

> Server-relative URLs are very similar to context-relative URLs, except
>   they do not assume you want your URL to be linking to a resource
>   inside your application’s context, and therefore allow you to link to
>   a different context in the same server

*Syntax:*

```
<img th:src="@{~/billing-app/images/Invoice.png}">
```

Output as:

```
<a href="/billing-app/showDetails.htm">
```

The above image will be loaded from an application different from your context and if an application named `billing-app` is present in your server.

*Sourced from: [Thymeleaf documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html)*

Comment: I have one issue : How to check in thymeleaf that given path in img url have source file or not, if source source file is available then show that otherwise show another file(image)instead of it.
my code ::
  <img class="w-100" th:src="'/uploadedImages/'+${userPostData.photo}" alt="">

Comment: What if I have a mix of resources from online (google search images) and resources from inside my spring boot application? It currently works for online resources using th:src="${my-link-here}" but it messes up once it is @{my-link-here}

Answer (score 15):

You need to understand how HTTP works. When the browser loads a page at URL

```
http://some.host/myWebApp/foo/bar.html
```

and the HTML page contains

```
<img src="images/test.png"/>
```

the browser will send a second HTTP request to the server to load the image. The URL of the image, since the path is relative, will be `http://some.host/myWebApp/foo/images/test.png`. Note that the absolute path is composed from the current "directory" of the page, concatenated with the relative path of the image. The path of the server-side JSP or thymeleaf template is completely irrelevant here. What matters is the URL of the page, as displayed in the address bar of the browser. This URL is, in a typical Spring MVC application, the URL of the controller where the initial request was sent.

If the path of the image is absolute:

```
<img src="/myWebApp/images/test.png"/>
```

then the browser will send a second request to the URL `http://some.host/myWebApp/images/test.png`. The browser starts from the root of the web server, and concatenates the absolute path.

To be able to reference an image, whetever the URL of the page is, an absolute path is thus preferrable and easier to use.

In the above example, `/myWebApp`is the context path of the application, that you typically don't want to hard-code in the path, because it might change. Thankfully, according to the [thymeleaf documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html), thymeleaf understands that and provides a syntax for context-relative paths, which thus transforms paths like `/images/test.png` into `/myWebApp/images/test.png`. So your image should look like

```
<img th:src="@{/images/test.png}"/>
```

(I've never used thymeleaf, but that's what I deduce from the documentation).

And the `test.png` image should thus be in a folder `images` located under the root of the webapp.

Answer (score 10):

Get link on Internet:

```
String src = "https://example.com/image.jpg";
```

HTML: `<img th:src="@{${src}}"/>`

Answer (score 4):

**I have used bellow like..**

My image path is like bellow..

[image]

I have used bellow code for loading image

```
 <img th:src="@{imges/photo_male_6.jpg}" >
```

It is working fine for me.

Answer (score 4):

Recently I had similar issue, but in my case, the spring security was making a problem. As mentioned in other answers and documentation:

```
<img th:src="@{/img/values.png}" alt="Media Resource"/>
```

should be enough. But since the spring security has been added to my project, I had to all **/img/** ** for get Requests and add **addResourceHandlers**. Here is the code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler(
                "/webjars/**",
                "/img/**",
                "/css/**",
                "/js/**")
                .addResourceLocations(
                        "classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/",
                        "classpath:/static/img/",
                        "classpath:/static/css/",
                        "classpath:/static/js/");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS);

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/js/**", "/css/**", "/img/**" ,"/pressiplus", "/public/**", "/index", "/", "/login").permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/secure/admin/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","USER")
                .antMatchers("/secure/admin/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
                .and()
                .formLogin()  //login configuration
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .failureUrl("/login-error")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                    .usernameParameter("email")
                    .passwordParameter("password")
                    .successHandler(myAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
                .and()
                .logout()    //logout configuration
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessHandler(myLogoutSuccessHandler)
                .and()
                    .rememberMe()
                        .tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository())
                        .tokenValiditySeconds(7 * 24 * 60 * 60) // expires in 7 days
                .and()
                    .exceptionHandling() //exception handling configuration
                .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler());
    }

}
```

I hope this helps someone in the future

Answer (score 3):

Who retrieve link dynamically use this pattern

```
<img class="image" th:src="@{'/resources/images/avatars/'+${theUser.avatar}}" alt="Avatar">
```

if you use like this `(${theUser.avatar})` it will add ? in above version link look like this: /resources/images/avatars/photoname.png

Answer (score 0):

As DimaSan said here https://stackoverflow.com/a/40914668/12312156
You should set image src like this:

```html
 <img src="../static/img/signature.png" th:src="@{img/signature.png}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Intellij Idea then you should do this:

> You don't need static in the path. You should use @{/images/logo.png} , because default resolver maps /src/main/resources/static/ to / url in your case.

I solved that problem with this. Source https://stackoverflow.com/a/46877798/

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked with flying saucerer:

```
    <img th:src="@{classpath:static/images/logo.png}"/></div>
```

Hope this can help!

Answer (score 0):

Summarize a litle bit from @Lucky.

1. Image under your project resources : `<img th:src="@{/images/test.png}"/>`
2. Image **outside** project resources (exp : fullpath on db, file on system) : `<img th:src="@{~/D:/images/test.png}"/>`
3. (bonus) Image having **whitespace**, convert whitespace char into `%20` in template : `<img th:src="@{~/D:/images/test%20amazing.png}"/>`
4. (bonus 2) concate injected from variable: `<img th:src="@{'~/' + ${myvar} }"/>`