# Image does not show using thymeleaf and spring

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

The image is in the following directory:

```
/src/main/resources/static/images/logo.png
```

And this is my HTML tag:

```
<img width="220px" height="70px" th:src="@{/static/images/logo.png}"/>
```

However, when i'm trying to access the image, this error shows up:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404). No message
>   available

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `static` in the path. You should use `@{/images/logo.png}`, because default resolver maps `/src/main/resources/static/` to `/` url in your case.

From [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content)

> By default Spring Boot will serve static content from a directory
>   called **/static** (or **/public** or **/resources** or **/META-INF/resources**) in
>   the classpath or from the root of the ServletContext.

Answer (score 2):

Also make sure that your image file name doesn't have any dash on it. For example if there is an image named '***book-icon.png***' the following will fail to compile:

```
<img width="220px" height="70px" th:src="@{/static/images/book-icon.png}"/>
```

Rename your file to '***bookicon.png***' (without dash) instead.
This code will work:

```
<img width="220px" height="70px" th:src="@{/static/images/bookicon.png}"/>
```