# How to use Thymeleaf / Spring / Eclipse to show image by '<img th:src '

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

problem:

```
<img src="@{/images/0.jpg}" alt="error occured"/>
```

I am using Eclipse and folder images is in **`src/main/resources/static/images`** and Thymeleaf template which uses:

```
<img src="@{/images/0.jpg}" alt="error occured"/>
```

is in folder: **`src/main/resources/templates`**

The image is for example: `1.jpg`

Comment: Probably your question is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29460618/inserting-an-image-from-local-directory-in-thymeleaf-spring-framework-with-mave/29475520

Comment: if I'm not wrong using standard html attribute name (src) with thymeleaf attrbute value evaluator (@{...}) won't do anything. What is your question? You want to replace src with th:src?

Comment: Yes.  I want use th:src="relative path". But in example to differ src and th:src. th:src is value obtained from controller right?  and src is constant used in thymeleaf src="images/1.jpg"/src="images/0.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

No, th:src is 'Thymeleaf Standard Dialect'. If your project is properly set up, spring/thymeleaf will be able to find your image on the webserver (e.g. Tomcat) by the given relative path itself. You do not need any own controller.

I hope this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29475520/9158389

Comment: Is this a mistake to create images folder in /resources/static/images or it should be /resources/images/0.jpg??

Comment: No this is not a mistake - you can have your images in "yourProject/src/main/resources/static/images". Just be sure, that this package is within the build path of your project. In Eclipse for example, just right click on yourProject -> Properties -> Java Build Path. Look at Source Tab if your resources package is there. If not, you have to add it. Click "Add Folder..." and pick your package.