# Spring Boot displays images in some pages but not others

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm facing issues with images in my Spring Boot + Thymeleaf application.

After reading a lot of fixes I'm able to show images in some of my app's pages but in other pages the images doesn't show.

I think that the number of paths in the request made is involved. It seems that requests to `/myaction` render pages showing images while requests to `/myaction/other` render pages not showing images.

In the fomer the successful request to obtain the images is:

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/images/logo.png
```

In the latter the failed request to obtain the images is:

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/myaction/images/logo.png
```

I append my configuration:

**In my implementation of WebMvcConfigurerAdapter:**

```
private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {
        "classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/",
        "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/"
};

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");

    registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
        .addResourceLocations(CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);
}
```

**Controller class:**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path="/myaction")
public class PagosController {
    @GetMapping(path="")
    public String show(Model model) {
    //...
    }

    @GetMapping(path="/other")
    public String show2(Model model) {
    //...
    }
}
```

**In my html template I load the image this way:**

```
<img th:src="@{images/logo.png}" />
```

**logo.png**

The file `logo.png` is located in `src/main/resources/static/images`

I have no clue why this is happening. Any idea on why images are getting requested at `http://localhost:8080/myapp/myaction/images/logo.png`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: think you need to use `<img th:src="@{/images/logo.png}" />` starting with a / (root),  have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29460618/inserting-an-image-from-local-directory-in-thymeleaf-spring-framework-with-mave)

Comment: @DirkDeyne Yeah, you are right (and I am ashamed). Post an answer and I'll accept it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your configuration, the images are available from the root **/**.

So you should be able to use `<img th:src="@{/images/logo.png}" />` in any page.