# How to load an image in spring boot with thymeleaf?

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to simply display an image in an html file in a spring boot application.

But for some reason I can't get it to work in one specific application.

I say "one specific application" because I could get it to work in the exact same way in another application.

This is how it is:

Placed tempLogo.jpg in the folder `/src/main/resources/static/images`.

In src/main/resources/templates/home.html:

```
<img src="images/tempLogo.jpg"></br>
<img src="/images/tempLogo.jpg"></br>
<img th:src="@{/images/tempLogo.jpg}"></br>
<img th:src="@{images/tempLogo.jpg}"></br>
```

None of this worked in app1.
All of these worked in app2 with the same code and paths.

Interesting enough, in app1 I can successfully access .css and .js files in the /static folder like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/styles.css"/>
<script src="/scripts/scripts.js"></script>
```

These are under:

`/src/main/resources/static/css`

`/src/main/resources/static/scripts`

Not sure what's going on since, like I said, in app2 that has the same exact path and code it did work.

Comment: Your code seems to be fine, maybe a typo in the filename? Also, what URL is being generated when using th:src?

Comment: Can't find any typo. This is what the th:src is generating: ```<img src="/images/tempLogo.jpg"></br> <img src="images/tempLogo.jpg"></br>```

Comment: `<img th:src="@{/images/tempLogo.jpg}">` is the way to go. In your post you are saying that you put img1.jpg in the folder, but that line references tempLogo.jpg. Any chance you got both mixed up?

Comment: no. I'm using just tempLogo.jpg in the code. Just in the question I called img1. I'm going to update the question to make it correct.

Comment: I ran a project clean in STS now and it worked! Seems there was some unknown garbage that was influencing on that.

Comment: now, let me ask you a question. Why do you say ```<img th:src="@{/images/tempLogo.jpg}">``` is the way to go? Why is that better than ```<img src="images/tempLogo.jpg">```?

Comment: Glad you made it work! It is better to use Context-relative urls or server-relative urls instead of absolute path. There's a great discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29460618/inserting-an-image-from-local-directory-in-thymeleaf-spring-framework-with-mave

Comment: but the second option is also relative. The only difference is that it's plain html.

Comment: The second option is relative to the current path, not to the application context.

Comment: what you mean by relative to the application context?

Comment: Just found out something else about the image thing. Although it loaded after the project clean, then it started to stop loading again. Then I reminded that I had security in the app. So I added the following code: ```web.ignoring().antMatchers("/images/**");``` in the spring security class. Then image started to load again. Think that was the real issue.

Comment: More on Context-relative urls in thymeleaf: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html. Regarding the other thing, it is still a weird behaviour, but I'm glad you sort it out. If that solved the problem, you should update the question and put what you just found out!

Comment: done. Just added the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging found out that the issue was that Spring security was not enabled for the images folder. So added `web.ignoring().antMatchers("/images/**");` in the configure method of the class that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and it worked.

```
@Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/css/**");      
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/scripts/**");
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/images/**");
    }
```