# How to do img in Thymeleaf?

Tags: thymeleaf

Why can't I display the picture after using the th:src?

```
<img th:src='@{/image/iphone.png}'/>
```

My resources:

[image]

Comment: remove the staring ‘/‘

Comment: Can you try if `http://localhost:8080/image/iphone.png` works in the browser? Also, can you check the generated HTML of your page in the browser to see what URL was generated by Thymeleaf?

Comment: I can't see the picture after try [http://localhost:8080/image/iphone.png]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inserting an image from local directory in thymeleaf spring framework (with maven)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29460618/inserting-an-image-from-local-directory-in-thymeleaf-spring-framework-with-mave)

Comment: Are there any `@Configuration` beans in your Spring Boot application? Or something like `@EnableWebMvc` somewhere? If so, try to comment it out and try again.